# Can't install OS X on blank HDD on a Macbook Pro 2010 13" - Stuck on white screen

Tags: hard-drive, startup, bootable-disk

I have a 2010 MacBook Pro lying around that I wanted to revive.

The problem is that I've lost the original DVDs. The original HDD is now blank and this version doesn't boot via USB.

I tried using a 2008 MacBook Pro DVD but it booted to the white screen and now it won't eject it. Boot shortcut keys (<kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> etc.) won't work either.

How can I proceed on this?

I have a HDD caddy, which is the DVD replacement, at my disposal if that helps.

Comment: Have you tried holding down [Opt ⌥] during startup? That starts into the *Startup Manager*. The *Startup Manager* allows you to select a macOS volume to start from at startup. If your 2010 MacBook Pro has a FireWire port and you have a FireWire drive with a version of macOS that your MacBook can boot from, than you can also use [T] during startup to startup in *FireWire Target Disk* mode. — Have you also tried holding down [C] during startup (starting from a CD/DVD), just in case? — You can also try hitting [Eject], [F12] or hold the mouse button at startup to try ejecting the DVD.

Answer (score 1):

That Mac to be able to use [Internet Recovery](https://support.apple.com/HT201314). Hold  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>    <kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd>   <kbd>R</kbd>  at the chimes

No Mac can boot to an OS older than itself.